# trouble exporting unirest req end data

Tags: javascript, api, module, export, unirest

How do I get minnStats to work outside the req.end function. I performing a get call from unirest, and I want to export the data. I'm not sure how to use the parameter of 'covidData' outside the req.end function though. How do i get the console.log on the bottom to work?

```
var unirest = require("unirest");

var req = unirest("GET", "https://covid-19-coronavirus-statistics.p.rapidapi.com/v1/stats");

req.query({
    "country": "US"
});

req.headers({
    "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-19-coronavirus-statistics.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "2e6a00a0b7mshb40a079e7a67f38p181597jsn5910590141c3"
});


req.end(function (covidData) {
    if (covidData.error) {
         throw new Error(covidData.error)
     } else {

    var covidStats = covidData.body.data.covid19Stats

    var minnStats = covidStats.filter(stat => stat.province === 'Minnesota')
    module.exports = minnStats

    console.table(minnStats)
    console.table(covidData.body)
    return covidData;
    }
})
console.log(minnStats)
```

Comment: Please dont post code as images. Copy it into your question and format it as code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the jquery code within the function, and then I used 'browserify' module so the js  would run on my browser regardless of the "require(unirest)" which otherwise causes it to error.